# Set Text Box property to MultiLine

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I am exercising some problems in Expresion blend.
My problem is with textbox property.I want it to show strings as multiline text,
but it goes horizontally right and I should put cursor on string and go to right along
with text.This is very annoying.
Any suggestions?

Here a picture of it:

[image]

My best regards and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to use the [TextWrapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textwrapping.aspx) property:

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```